# jrequest doesn't work after a simple change

Tags: javascript, ajax, joomla

i'm editing a joomla website and in a form I needed to swap some dropdown select boxes with simple text fields. for example I swapped this:

```
<select name="date" id="date" class="date_tag">
<?php   for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)   {   ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if($i == date('d')) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>

    <?php   }   ?>
    </select>
```

with that:

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="date_tag">
```

in the final proccessing of the form I can't get the values of the fields I swapped from select
boxes to text fields.
although there are other text fields in this form. I can't tell what's different.
the processing is done with JRequest as in here:

```
if(JRequest::getInt('step', 0) == 2)    {   
global $mainframe;  
$fstate     = JRequest::getVar('fstate', '');
$fzip       = JRequest::getVar('fzip', '');
$tstate     = JRequest::getVar('tstate', '');
$tzip       = JRequest::getVar('tzip', '');
$month      = JRequest::getVar('month', '');
$date       = JRequest::getVar('date', '');
$year       = JRequest::getVar('year', '');
$weight     = JRequest::getVar('weight', '');
$type       = JRequest::getVar('type', '');
$first_name = JRequest::getVar('first_name', '');
$last_name  = JRequest::getVar('last_name', '');
$email      = JRequest::getVar('email', '');
$phone_type = JRequest::getVar('phone_type2', '');
$phone_num  = JRequest::getVar('phone_num', '');
$time       = JRequest::getVar('time2', '');
    ....
```

i get that $date='' even when I entered a value to that field.
as I said it worked before I made the swap.
what could be the problem?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like there is something else going on here, as the new input field appears to be correct.

I would suggest using print_r($_POST) and tracing through the data.

Comment: all I can see from the trace is that the relevant post information for the date is really empty

Comment: Array ( [first_name] => A [last_name] => B [email] => tomr2005@gmail.com [phone_num] => 123 [phone_type] => [time] => [fstate] => [fzip] => 1 [tstate] => [tzip] => 2 [month] => 5 [date] => [year] => 2011 [weight] => [type] => [step] => 2 [phone_type2] => [time2] => [submit] => Submit )

Comment: You might consider using an alternative name for the input field. For example, try changing it to date2, and then see if you see the same result. If the other field also still exists AFTER the new code, then it is probably overriding it with a blank value.